# How to connect chrome extension to web application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, auth0

How can I connect our chrome extension to our web application? 
Our web application displays a list of wish list items to their user dashboard. The chrome extension grabs the information on the page of the item a user is viewing on a button click in the extension. 
We need users to be able to login to the chrome extension using Auth0 to connect to their user account from the web application. 
The chrome extension takes active tab information on the button click, creates a Link Preview via MicroLink API which includes URL, Image Source, Title, and Description in a JSON response. 
We need to access/receive and store that JSON response to the Users table so that we can render a react component to that users wish list/dashboard when they log into the Web Application.

How can we go about making the two communicate? Does the Chrome Extension need to live within the Web React Application, or does it need to be a separate application?

````
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            itemURL: 'https://www.item.url'
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
            const itemURL = new URL(tabs[0].url);
            this.setState({
                itemURL: itemURL,
            });
            console.log(itemURL);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ItemWrapper>
                <MicrolinkCard
                    className='item-shadow'
                    url={this.state.itemURL}
                    media={['video', 'image', 'logo', 'screenshot']}
                    size='large'
                />
            </ItemWrapper>
        )
    }```
````

Comment: A chrome extension doesn't live inside web content by definition; it's a browser extension living in the browser. Why do you need a chrome extension for this in the first place? If all it does is extend your own web app, chances are its functionality can be implemented as part of the web app instead.

Comment: See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#external-webpage